# Problem with displacement map when creating collection instances

Tags: subdivision-surface, displacement, instances, collections, height-map

I am trying to create collections of instances from an object with a material, which includes a displacement map.
When rendering, for some reason the displacement of the instance collection does not look the same as the original object.
If I directly duplicate the original object, both copies do show exactly the same displacement without any variation. However I can't use this technique because my project would be too overloaded.

Is there any way to fix this in the instance collections?
I attach here two pictures so you can see what I mean, for some reason the instance doesn't seem to detect the subdivision of the original object and that's why it shows it with less detail (or at least that's what I think, but I don't know how to solve it).
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What space is your displacement in ? Can you show the shader-tree?

Comment: Yes of course, I just added the image with my materials node in my post.